# python - ImportError: cannot import name import_module

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run chatterbot example with this guide: http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

So i'm getting this import error:

```
➜  examples git:(master) python basic_example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic_example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chatterbot/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .logic import MultiLogicAdapter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chatterbot/logic/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .logic_adapter import LogicAdapter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chatterbot/logic/logic_adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.utils import import_module
ImportError: cannot import name import_module
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/chatterbot/`

If you see a directory named `utils` delete it.

Also if you see a directory named `adapters` delete it.

they talked about this issue here [ImportError: cannot import name 'import_module'](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/443)